# Inserting table and figure vertically in a full page

Tags: tables, floats, rotating

I have a table with large number of columns and few rows. I need to insert this table vertically in one single page. How to do. I need to do the same with a figure also, wherein I need to insert a figure in a single page

Comment: Hello, I need to orient the entire object(table and figure) vertically not just vertically centered ! Thanks for the link anyway !

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the package `rotating`, which provides the environment `sidewaystable`. Your code should look as follows. Notice that the table takes **one whole page** (page 2). There is analogous environment `sidewaysfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % <-- HERE

\begin{document}

blabla dummy text

\begin{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}\hline
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption to the table.}
\end{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried using sideways figure I get the following error ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: That means you have used a figure or table environment inside a minipage or parbox. Presumably you don't get that error if you run the code in the answer posted?

Comment: I have not used the figure inside a minibox or parbox ! I did not get the error if I run the code posted.

Comment: LaTeX thinks you did:-), can you post a small example that shows the error (just edit it in to your question)

Comment: I got the mistake. I used the figure package within the sideways figure which was creating the problem. Thanks for you help !